# SonarQube 10 - installation stopped in Windows 11

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I tried to install SonarQube 10 in my system but not able to complete the installation.

I have Java version 20 and set the environment path correctly but still facing the issue.

[image]